# Drawback to having cache enabled, but sized to 0 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Is there a performance hit, or any other drawbacks to leaving query caching enabled in MySQL 5, but sizing the cache to 0 bytes?

I assume that any performance impact would be minimal if any, but I'm wondering if there are any other issues which might arise that I have not considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the [query_cache_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_size) to 0 will disable [query caching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-configuration.html) completely at MySQL.

[So when it is good idea to use query cache?](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/27/mysql-query-cache/)

Comment: Wonderful!  Searching a little deeper revealed that the size was what determined if caching was on or not, and not have_query_cache.

Also, thanks for the link on when it is a good idea to use cache!  It was a great read.